# HTML elements - of distinct types, but sharing the same class name - behaving strangely

Tags: html, css

So I'm building a website, which features several pages describing (fantasy) people and places. To that end, several categories of page have a `profilebox` which include stuff like a heading, an image and a table with some summary data.

The HTML for such a box looks like this:

```html
<profilebox class="red">
  <p><i>His Majesty</i><br><span class="big-and-strong">The King</span>
  </p>
  <figure class="pbox"><img class="pbox" src="../images/armsroyal.svg"> 
  </figure>
  <table class="pbox">
    <tr>
      <td>Surname</td>
      <td>N/A</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Forename</td>
      <td>N/A</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Rank</td>
      <td>King</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Addressed As</td>
      <td>&lsquo;&lsquo;Your Majesty&rsquo;&rsquo;</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</profilebox>
```

Whereas the CSS looks like this:

```css
profilebox {
  display: block;
  margin-top: 1em;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  margin-left: 1em;
  margin-right: 0em;
  width: 400px;
  float: right;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 1em;
  border-color: black;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0px 0px 0px 5px;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 600px;
}

.mini {
  width: 400px;
}

.maxi {
  width: 100%;
}

.pbox {
  width: 100%;
}

img {
  margin: 1em;
}

.pbox {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 100%;
}

figure.pbox {
  width: 100%;
}
```

Now the `pbox` class of table has width set to 100%, so the table in the profile box should fill up its parent element, right? (I can feel a "Wrong!" coming on.) However, this is what the page actually looks like in Chromium:

[Table too narrow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dwmQ5.png)

If I replace `<table class="pbox">` with `<table class="maxi">`, I get the desired result:

[Table just right](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WrEU7.png)

**But the `maxi` and `pbox` classes of table are identical!** Any idea what's going on here?

Comment: you have `display: block;` in the pbox which is enough to break the table

Comment: Cool. Thank you. But why does the table **un**-break when I change its class from `pbox` to `maxi`?

Comment: because you have display:block defined only inside `pbox`

Comment: Forgive me if I'm being stupid, but `display: block;` is only in the **`img`** version of the `pbox` class. The `table` version of the `pbox` class simply reads `width: 100%`. Is this the issue? Is CSS getting the different `pbox` classes muddled up?

Comment: If you want to apply `display: block` to only the img pbox you must say so in the selector: i.e `img.pbox { display: block }` similar to what you did with `figure.pbox`.

Comment: Thank you, @Alohci! I took the gist of what you said, and put it into an answer to my own question. Tell me if I've misunderstood anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had assumed - incorrectly - that if you put something like:

CSS

```css
element1 {
  property-a: setting1;
}

.class-name {
  property-b: setting2;
}

element2 {
  property-c: setting3;
}

.class-name {
  property-d: setting4;
}
```

HTML

```html
  <element2 class="class-name"/>
```

Then `element2` will have properties:

- `property-c: setting3;`
- `property-d: setting4;`

In fact, **all** definitions of `.class-name` will be applied, so `element2` will have properties:

- `property-b: setting2;`
- `property-c: setting3;`
- `property-d: setting4;`

If we amend the CSS as follows:

```css
element1 {
  property-a: setting1;
}

element1.class-name {
  property-b: setting2;
}

element2 {
  property-c: setting3;
}

element2.class-name {
  property-d: setting4;
}
```

Then everything works!